# Node.js: How to increase readline/inquirer prompt height

Tags: node.js, yeoman, readline

I'm using `inquirer.js` for creating a `yeoman-generator` and when it comes to a long list as prompt the height of it is too short to show all items. How can I increase it?. I know `inquirer.js` uses an extended version of node.js's `readline`, I don't know if the limitation is on this module.

Pic related:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

@Evgenly answer points to the correct option but I didn't find the github link particularly useful.

The `pageSize` attribute allow to control the number of items to display:

```
inquirer
  .prompt([
    {
      type: 'rawlist',
      pageSize: 12,
      name: 'event',
      message: 'question?',
      choices: [
        'option1',
        'option2',
        'option3',
        'option4',
        'option5',
        'option6',
        'option7',
        'option8',
        'option9',
        'option10',
        'option11',
        'exit',
      ]
    },
  ])
```

This will output the whole 12 options in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pageSize` to set num of items on page, [more info](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/61)

Comment: Didn't find the [above link to the closed github issue](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/61) that useful, but inquirer now [supports `pageSize` as a question option](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/#question)

Answer (score 0):

Just scroll up and down (up and down arrow) to display the choices who're below the fold.

Inquirer doesn't (and won't) provide an option to manually set the height of the list being displayed. That being said, that height might change in the future as we plan on using the height of the user terminal.

Comment: Hi Simon, you say inquirer won't provide that option, but then that the height might change in the future using the height user terminal and i find that confusing.

Comment: It means there won't be an option to manually configure the height.